# Nodemailer with Express App won't send email on Button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

Using the default set up from the [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer), the email will send with our internal mail server just fine when the app starts up with all code included on the app.js page.

```
//app.js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.oursite.com',
});
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'couponrequest@company.com', // sender address
  to: 'myaddy@company.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
  text: 'Hello world ✔', // plaintext body
  html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // html body
};
// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

Then when switching things around it breaks and nothing happens when trying to make it happen from a button click.

**App.js**:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
app.get('/users', routes.users);
```

**Users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

/*
 * POST to addcoupon Request.
 */
router.post('/addcoupon', function(req, res) {
  // create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.primeshine.com',
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

/*
 * POST to addcoupon Request.
 */
router.post('/addcoupon', function(req, res) {
  // create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.primeshine.com',
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Global.js**

```
// Add Coupon Request
function addCoupon(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'couponrequest@company.com', // sender address
    to: 'myaddy@company.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ✔', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  });
};
```

I tried to use only the relevant code to send it. It works fine sending info to MongoDB for the button when it is adding user info but it doesn't submit anything when I try to have it send an email. Not sure if I have something in the wrong place or if something else is wrong... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using Nodemailer on client-side javascript (Global.js)? It's only meant for server-side

Comment: Thanks, new to this and that makes a ton of sense. Had to implement it in a different way so thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I used nodemailer to send emails from my email account I had to create the transport with authentication:

```
/* define transportation */
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'posteo.de',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    },
    maxConnections: 5,
    maxMessages: 10
}));
```

Not sure if this if this is necessary for in your case but maybe it helps.

Comment: No, it works fine without authentication. It was where I was trying to have it run the code that was the issue. But thanks for the comment!